# PHP regular expression to detect if url is to an image file

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm very new to regular expressions and need a little help with something complicated.

I have a list of URLs that may as well be in an array that would look like this:

```
$urls = array(
    "http://example.com/page.php",
    "http://example.com/page.php?key=value",
    "http://example.com/image.jpg",
    "http://example.com/image.jpg?key=value" ...
```

I want to loop over the array (which is simple enough with `foreach`) and for each string return true if the URL points to a file that is an image. I have the following regular expression:

```
"#\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$# i"
```

... but it seems to only return true is the string ends in one of the given image extensions. I need to compensate for two factors: 1. if the string has a URL query string on the end of it (ie. `?key=value`) and whether the extenion (eg. `jpg`) is actually part of the query string to a non-image file, for example:

```
http://example.com/page.php?image=file.jpg
```

Should return false because the URL is pointing to a PHP file, not a jpg

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Just an FYI: Unless you actually retrieve it, you cannot know that `page.php` *does not* return an image

Comment: that's ok, i can check the content-type as a fallback, thanks!

Comment: @Sjon: a happy middle ground might be a HEAD request, trusting the web server to assign the correct Content-Type. OP: you won't *have* a Content-Type unless you make a request, is what he's saying.

Comment: Well, I do not like the one-regex solution here: [`'~^(?!.*\?.*(\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)\b)).*(?1)(?:$|\?)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/pJ5uG0/2)

Comment: Check https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-50 on how to properly parse a URL. In your case $6 must end in your declared extensions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why over-complicate it. Just select everything but a `?`, like so, `[^?]+`. That removes the `?`. Then just use the original RegEx and add it to the end, much shorter: [`^[^?]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)`](https://regex101.com/r/pX3hO6/2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Complete RegEx Version

Actually, here is a complete RegEx version:

```
^[^?]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/pX3hO6/2)</kbd>

How it works:

```
^[^?]*                  # Removes ?foo=bar&baz=foo
\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)    # Image Extension
```

The first part selects everything up to the `?...`. It is the RegEx equivalent to selecting the first item from `explode('?', $str)`. The second part is the same as yours, with the `$` removed (since the end of the string may be variables after the `?`)

---

To deal with the following cases of unusual File Extensions like:

- **`test.jpgfoo`**
- **`test.pngbar`**
- **`test.jpg.nope`**
- **`image.jpg-test.php`**
- **`image.jpg_test.php`**

Add a **Negative Lookahead** to the end, **`(?![\w.\-_])`**:

```
^[^?]*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)(?![\w.\-_])
```

This will make sure there are no letters, another extension, `.`, `-` or `_` after the accepted file extension. If there are, the RegEx will fail

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/iG6cK4/1)</kbd>

---

This RegEx will do what you need, if you do as **@DevilaN** said and `explode('?', $str)`:

```
\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)(\?.*)?$
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/sL5uC0/1)</kbd>

Comment: @DevilaN I added an update for those unusual cases. Just put `(?!\w)` at the end, to make sure there are no more letters after the accepted file extension

Comment: @DevilaN Thanks, fixed that too!

Comment: @DevilaN Seriously! `;)` I don't even think that is a valid File Extension, but I have fixed it, as well as any with `_`! Any others?

Comment: Yup. http://example.com/test.png+file.php http://example.com/test.png~file.php and many many others

Generally read section 2: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2 :)

Comment: @DevilaN Wow! That'll take ages to include! If the OP wants to do that, he can add then to the Negative Lookahead himself. `;)`. Wait, I now see how your solution makes more sense!

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is ok, but you need to get rid of ?something=something
Just explode("?", $string); and use first part which will contain url with filename only. Then proceed with your normal regex.

```
$urls = array(
    "http://example.com/page.php",
    "http://example.com/page.php?key=value",
    "http://example.com/image.jpg",
    "http://example.com/image.jpg?key=value"
);

function isImage($l) {
    $arr = explode("?", $l);
    return preg_match("#\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$# i", $arr[0]);
}
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo $url . ": " .(isImage($url) ? "true" : "false") . "\n";
}
```

And the result is:

```
http://example.com/page.php: false
http://example.com/page.php?key=value: false
http://example.com/image.jpg: true
http://example.com/image.jpg?key=value: true
```

If you want pure regular expression solution then:

```
function isImage($l) {
    return preg_match("/^[^\?]+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)(?:\?|$)/", $l);
}
```